# One can call a base class function from a derived class function with the same name. But I can't find a quote from the Standard supporting this

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following snippet:

```
struct Base{
   void f() {}
};

struct Derived: public Base{
   void f() { Base::f(); }
};

Derived d;
int main(){
    d.f();
}
```

The snippet works fine. i.e., `d.f()` calls `Base::f()`. But I can't find a quote from the standard supporting this.

Comment: [class.qual]...

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I was looking at [\[class.call\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.qual#class.qual-1) and it seems to answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: See also the last paragraph (which should be non-normative I think)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I believe you're talking about paragraph [3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.qual#class.qual-3) . That's perfect. Thank you .Why do you say it should be non-normative?

Comment: @JohnKalane The rules of paragraph 1 applies here: lookup in the scope of the class which has been nominated by the nested name specifier. This rule will not be affected by shadowing on the call site, as we are using a qualified name. Paragraph 3, on the other hand, gives a _specific_ example of how paragraph 1 can apply / the effect of it. These kind of segments in the standard are typically non-normative (examples, notes, and so on), whereas paragraph 3, which brings no ”new” normative value (already covered in 1) is not wrapped as a note or an example. It arguably should be (non-normative).

Comment: @dfrib Seems like an answer with a bit of fleshing out.

Comment: @cigien Ok, I did some fleshing out! :) I was waiting for LanguageLawyer to answer it as he first suppled the normative link, but it seems he was content with a comment for this one.

Comment: @dfrib Thanks for adding an answer. Yeah, I think there was ample time for anyone to write an answer. Generally, the LL tag doesn't suffer from FGITW, so as long as you attribute the user's comment (as you did), you don't have to worry about waiting too long for them to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>*All standard references below refer to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

This is [[class.qual]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.qual#1) [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> If the *nested-name-specifier* of a qualified-id **nominates a class, the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier* is looked up in the scope of the class** [...]

In your example, `Base::` is the *nested-name-specifier*, and the name specified after it is `f()`, for which lookup is thus performed in the scope of the class `Base`. This rule will not be affected by shadowing on the call site, as we are using a qualified name, and we may note that if we remove `f()` from `Base` the qualified id will (as expected for qualified lookup) not search for `f()` of the scope of the derived class.

```
struct Base {};

struct Derived: public Base {
   void f() { 
       Base::f();  // error: 'f' is not a member of 'Base
   }
};
```

We may also note that [[class.qual]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.qual#3) particularly mentions this case:

> A class member name hidden by a name in a nested declarative region or by the name of a derived class member can still be found if qualified by the name of its class followed by the ​`::`​ operator.

but as pointed out [in a comment by @LanguageLawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65127825/one-can-call-a-base-class-function-from-a-derived-class-function-with-the-same-n?noredirect=1#comment115141410_65127825), this paragraph should arguably be non-normative<sup>(1)</sup>.

---

<sub>*(1) [class.qual]/3 gives a specific example of how [class.qual]/1 can apply / the effect of it. However, these kind of segments in the standard are typically non-normative (examples, notes, and so on), whereas [class.qual]/3, which brings no ”new normative" value (already covered in [class.qual]/1), is not wrapped as a note or an example.*</sub>